# Please advise regarding symbols _setjmp, longjmp and others designated as "W" (weak) in libc.a

Tags: compilation, reference, fortran, undefined

I am trying to cross-compile Fortran code to run on x86_64 processor, and built a cross-compiler x86_64-linux-android-gfortran to do so.  I am using the -static flag on the compile because that's how, based on previous experience, I was successfully able to execute the resulting binary on an Android device.  My problem is this: when building one Fortran module, I am getting undefined references to _setjmp, longjmp, and a few others.  I have linked into the compile, Android NDK revision 21, libc.a.  When I broke out the libc.a archive, and did "nm *.o" on the resulting object files, I see that _setjmp and longjmp are defined as "W" (weak).  Is there some way around this?  I do not understand what "weak" means despite checking one definition.  Please, can someone advise me on this and how I can fix?
TIA,
Steve

Comment: Just to clarify, the libc.a is from android-ndk-r21d/platforms/android-30/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64.

Comment: I see that android-ndk-r21d/platforms/android-30/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/libc.so has _setjmp and longjmp defined as "T", i.e., defined (not weak as in libc.a).  Even though I am compiling with "gcc -static", is there any way to include the defined symbols, _setjmp and longjmp, from libc.so, rather than the undefined (weak) symbols, _setjmp and loingjmp, from libc.a?  If not, can someone then provide some C source code for _setjmp and longjmp so I can build a lib.a file from that source?  Thanks.